# I want to make this a global variable but I dont know what Im doing wrong replacing image src code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with turning this each function statement into a global variable, can anybody help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imageurl = '';
  var imageSrc = "";
    $(".card__image").each(function(){
      var imageurl = this;
      var imagesrc = "";
      //imageData = $(this).data('src');
      imagesrc = $(this).attr("src");
      imagesrc = imagesrc.replace('http://*', 'https://*');
      imageSrc = imagesrc;
      //console.log(imagesrc);
      return imageSrc;
});
    console.log(imageSrc);
    //alert(imagesrcrw);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what is "wrong". It seems like you are asking about how to replace a specific part of a string. Please clarify the issue, any errors you see, or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `return`ing anything in a jQuery `.each` loop is pointless. You're all the way at the end of the loop when you `console.log(imageSrc)`, so you'll only get the last result. `.replace` just replaces and returns a new String, it does not assign to the old one. Why do you need to use JavaScript to change your protocol? Just use your editor. If you force the protocol to https with your Server, you can actually just do like `//somesite.com/any_img.png`. Of course, I have to ask why you're not  just using relative paths, if the images are on your own site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {
  var allImgSrc = [];
  var imagesrc;
  $(".card__image").each(function(i, el) {
    imagesrc = $(el).attr("src").replace('http://', 'https://');
    $(el).attr("src", imagesrc);
    allImgSrc.push(imagesrc);
  });
  console.log(allImgSrc);
});
```

This defines an Array called `allImgSrc`. We then loop over all `.card__image` elements and replace the `src` attribute.

In the console, you should see the populated array.

**See More**

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace